# What is the best way to find if a directed graph is is bipartite?

Tags: algorithm, directed-graph, bipartite

Various pieces of codes are available to determine if an undirected graph is bipartite, I am unable get a good working logic for directed graph. Although the directed graph can be converted an undirected one and the process can be carried out, it seems much of an overhead! Is there an better solution for the same?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe this should instead be asked on the mathematics SE?

Comment: (No eval of performance, but a remark): networkx does try a [2-coloring](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/algorithms/bipartite/basic.html#is_bipartite) (which is in P). These university [slides](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2014-15/1term/ma006a/class9.pdf) also give the implication: undirected graph 2-colorable ->  bipartite.

Comment: Intuitively, I'd also just have tried a 2-coloring, following a DFS of the graph. Whenever you hit a node that has already been colored in the "wrong" color, the graph is not bipartite. Should work just as well for a directed or undirected graph.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to test for bipartite in directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857758/how-to-test-for-bipartite-in-directed-graph)

Comment: @yeputons Good find.